# How to execute a MySql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm executing a simple delete query in mysql using php. I don't know wrong with this query:

```
  $delid=$_REQUEST['did'];
if(($del=mysql_query("delete from achieva_trainee_mail_tble where id='".$delid."'"))==true)
{
    header("location:viewtrainee.php?dl=1");
}
else
{
    echo("<script>alert('Failure please try again later...');</script>");
}
```

I can get the 'did' in the page using '$_REQUEST['did']. But it isn't redirecting to the viewtrainee.php page, it goes to the else part. I execute the same structure for other files it works fine. What is wrong with this.

Comment: First remove quotes from "where id=.." as your ID is INTEGER. Second be sure you do not have any output or HTML tag before, as header() only works then.

Comment: use var_dump to check what mysql_query returns you

Comment: use `mysql_error()` to catch errors...

Comment: @lukas.pukenis I've changed this line   if(($del=mysql_query("delete from achieva_trainee_mail_tble where id=".$delid))==true).   But still I get 'false' from the mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)** function.

```
$delid=$_REQUEST['did'];

mysql_query("delete from achieva_trainee_mail_tble where id='".$delid."'"));

if(mysql_affected_rows())
{
    header("location:viewtrainee.php?dl=1");
}
else
{
    echo("<script>alert('Failure please try again later...');</script>");
}
```

Comment: Always use mysql_real_escape_string instead of using quote. i.e.  mysql_query("delete from achieva_trainee_mail_tble where id=".mysql_real_escape_string($delid)));

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query return the result and not the success state... use mysql_error or mysql_errno like this:

```
$didName = 'did';
$delId = null;
$failed = true;

if(array_key_exists($didName, $_REQUEST)) {
    $delId = $_REQUEST[$didName];
    mysql_query("delete from achieva_trainee_mail_tble where id='".mysql_real_escape_string($delId, $yourConnection)."'", $yourConnection);

    if(false == mysql_errno($yourConnection)) {
        $failed = true;
    }
}

if(false == $failed) {
       header("location:viewtrainee.php?dl=1");
}
else {
    echo("<script>alert('Failure please try again later...');</script>");
}
```

Comment: And you can use mysql_error(); to get the error message: it's probably that you're referencing an unknown table, unless your table really is called "tble" :) 

Note the importance of escaping *all* input data coming from the user: you must use mysql_real_escape_string before putting it into the query, to avoid users using SQL injection to delete your entire database!